# How is the performance of the PhoneGap developer app compared to the finished app?

Tags: phonegap

I am using the PhoneGap Developer app for iOS to preview and test my PhoneGap app on my iPhone.

I am wondering: if everything runs smoothly there - does that mean it will run as smoothly (or better?) if a user eventually runs the finished app from the App Store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the device of course, about its preforms and its strength.
Try using a small number of scripts because of course the phonegap is a web browser converted to a mobile application, so if you are familiar with web programming, you will find that a growing number of huge scripts slow down the web page and require more memory from the user.

You can definitely try the app on your Android device and you'll see that the preforms are great.
Compile here: [Build phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/), and download it on your device.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @proofzy ! I meant on the **same device** :) I'm running the PhoneGap Developer app on my iPhone 7. Can I expect the same (or better) performance on my iPhone 7 if I run the finished app (after downloading it from the App Store once it's approved)?

Comment: @TonaldDrump It will be quite the same! I have already 4 app's and preformance is very good, unless you have a mistake with javascript (you can allways use inspect element / tab preformance)..